# R: efficiently identifying highest N values of variable Z by group X

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a datatable that looks like this.

```
ID <- c(rep("ABC",4), rep("DEF",4), rep("GHI",5))
X  <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4),3),5)
set.seed(1234)
Z  <- runif(13,min=0, max =1)  
a <- data.table(ID, X, Z)
a

     ID X           Z
 1: ABC 1 0.113703411
 2: ABC 2 0.622299405
 3: ABC 3 0.609274733
 4: ABC 4 0.623379442
 5: DEF 1 0.860915384
 6: DEF 2 0.640310605
 7: DEF 3 0.009495756
 8: DEF 4 0.232550506
 9: GHI 1 0.666083758
10: GHI 2 0.514251141
11: GHI 3 0.693591292
12: GHI 4 0.544974836
13: GHI 5 0.282733584
```

I'd like to produce a dataframe that has the N highest values of Z within each X subgroup. So lets say N is 2. I'd like to end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
   X  ID         Z
1: 1 DEF 0.8609154
2: 1 GHI 0.6660838
3: 2 DEF 0.6403106
4: 2 ABC 0.6222994
5: 3 GHI 0.6935913
6: 3 ABC 0.6092747
7: 4 ABC 0.6233794
8: 4 GHI 0.5449748
9: 5 GHI 0.2827336
```

I've been using this line to achive it, but I've found it to be particularly slow when the datatable is large (i.e. over 1,500,000 lines or more.)

```
top_n <- 2
a <- a[order(a$X, -a$Z),]
a_2 <- a[, head(.SD, top_n), by=X]
a_2

   X  ID         Z
1: 1 DEF 0.8609154
2: 1 GHI 0.6660838
3: 2 DEF 0.6403106
4: 2 ABC 0.6222994
5: 3 GHI 0.6935913
6: 3 ABC 0.6092747
7: 4 ABC 0.6233794
8: 4 GHI 0.5449748
9: 5 GHI 0.2827336
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, there is no need to assign with `<-` at intermediate steps, since `a[order(a$X, -a$Z),][, head(.SD, top_n), by=X]` and `a[order(a$X, -a$Z), head(.SD, top_n), by=X]` do the same thing. Also, you do not need to include `a$` when you are working inside the data.table brackets `a[]`. Finally, there is no need to order by `X` ahead of time to see the results in order (`keyby=X` does the same thing) though it may be faster (as suggested in David's answer below, with `setorder`). Just fyi regarding some pitfalls.

Answer (score 5):

This should be faster than `.SD`

```
n <- 2
indx <- a[order(-Z), .I[seq_len(n)], by = X]$V1
a[indx]
#      ID  X         Z
#  1: DEF  1 0.8609154
#  2: GHI  1 0.6660838
#  3: GHI  3 0.6935913
#  4: ABC  3 0.6092747
#  5: DEF  2 0.6403106
#  6: ABC  2 0.6222994
#  7: ABC  4 0.6233794
#  8: GHI  4 0.5449748
#  9: GHI  5 0.2827336
# 10:  NA NA        NA
```

If you need an ordered result, this should be also fast

```
setorder(a, X, -Z)
indx <- a[, .I[seq_len(n)], by = X]$V1
a[indx]
#      ID  X         Z
#  1: DEF  1 0.8609154
#  2: GHI  1 0.6660838
#  3: DEF  2 0.6403106
#  4: ABC  2 0.6222994
#  5: GHI  3 0.6935913
#  6: ABC  3 0.6092747
#  7: ABC  4 0.6233794
#  8: GHI  4 0.5449748
#  9: GHI  5 0.2827336
# 10:  NA NA        NA
```

Comment: where are the `NA`s coming from?

Comment: @MichaelChirico It's coming from asking for the top 2 obs even though there might only be a single obs. To get rid of it, one could put `min(.N,n)` in place of `n` in the `seq_len`

Comment: @Frank I think the fastest option would be to wrap the final result into `na.omit` instead of running `min` per group.

Comment: `head(.I,n)` would also be a safe option. I'm guessing it is not slow. Oh, I'm surprised to see that `head`, internally, is the same as you've written here, so yeah, maybe `na.omit` ex post is best.